# JNA equivalent of PVOID

Tags: jna

what is the representation of PVOID in JNA?

Answer (score 6):

PVOID is a **Pointer** to anything. The equivalent JNA class should be [Pointer](https://jna.dev.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html).